# Show a function converges to 0 uniformly on [0,1]?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of functions defined on $[0,1]$.  Show that if $(f_n)$ converges to zero uniformly on $[0,1]$, then for any sequence of points $(x_n)$ with $x_n \in [0,1]$ for every $n$, the sequence $f_n(x_n)$ has limit zero.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Kindly show your work, even if only partial.

Comment: I think I have the main idea, but I'm not quite sure of the wording. Since (fn) converges uniformly to zero for all n, the limit clearly exists, but I am not sure what reasoning can be used to show the limit is zero.

Comment: Assume not. Argue by contradiction.

Comment: For every $n$, $|f_n(x_n)| \le \sup_{x \in [0,1]} |f_n(x)|$.  But the right side goes to 0 as $n \to \infty$...

Comment: You can prove, as a previous exercise, that $f_n\to f$ uniformly in $A$ if and only if the sequence of numbers $\sup_{x\in A} \vert f_n(x)-f(x)\vert$ converges to $0$. Then, look at the Nate's comment.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly to $0$, given $\epsilon>0$, there is an $N$ so that $|f_m(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $m>N$ and all $x\in[0,1]$.

To show that the sequence $\{f_n(x_n)\}$ has limit $0$, you need to show that for every $\epsilon>0$, there is an $N$ so that $|f_m(x_m)|<\epsilon$ for all $m>N$.

Can you see how to put these together to get what you want?

Comment: But how can the |fn(xm)|< epsilon if the function isn't explicitly defined?

Comment: @phillips0023: Because you use the *structure* available to you. You've been told that you have a sequence of functions $(f_n)$ which converge *uniformly* to zero on $[0,1]$. That is a rather strong statement to make about the $(f_n)$. Indeed, it is enough to allow you to arrive at the conclusion without having to say anything more explicit about the nature of $(f_n)$.

Comment: @phillips0023 I'm sorry; what function? The limit function is the zero function: $|f_m(x_m)-0|=|f_m(x_m)|$. From  the first paragraph, you can make $|f_n(x)|$ as small as you like $for\  all$ numbers  $x\in[0,1]$ as long as $n$ is sufficiently large, and that includes the $x$'s in the given sequence.